# What did dot (between two key words) mean in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm64

I saw a assembly like:

```
b.gt memzero
```

I think I know the meaning of `b.gt` but not sure why the syntax is legal. By developer [guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/ARM-Instruction-Reference/ARM-branch-instructions/B-and-BL?lang=en), I've not seen any syntax like this.

Are there any document regulate this kind of syntax? Or how can I call it?

Comment: assembly language is specific to the tool not the target (note arm has multiple targets).  in this case this looks to be a branch if greater than to the label memzero.  What did you think it meant?

Comment: what tools are you using and what did the disassembly show (machine code vs the manual)

Comment: I think the same as you (What b.gt mean). This assembly will be compiled to object file by aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc. I just be confused about why we can write something like this (with dot).

Comment: @Steven The developer guide you have there is for 32 bit ARM whereas your code is for 64 bit ARM.  Do not mix up these two, they are quite different in any regard.

Comment: In many assemblers, a dot is treated just like a letter in forming identifiers and keywords. I think there is nothing special about the dot in this case--it's just how the keyword is spelled.

Comment: At least on early 32-bit ARM CPUs (I don't know about 64-bit ARM CPUs) all instructions could be executed conditionally (e.g. `ANDS` - unconditional or `ANDGTS` - only if flags indicate a `GT` condition). It is much easier to write an assembler that requires the condition to be separated from the rest (e.g. `ANDS.GT` instead of `ANDGTS`). If the syntax is legal? It's the manufacturer of the assembler who defines what is legal and what is not legal. So if the manufacturer decides that `ANDGTS` is written as `ANDS.GT`, you have to write it this way.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: AArch64 does *not* have universal predication of all instructions.  Unlike AMD64 vs. IA32, it's a whole new machine-code format, with predicates only for branches and a couple nice branchless building-block instructions like CSINC (conditional select increment) that allows (with AArch64's zero register) materializing a boolean 0 / 1, or doing `x += (condition)` conditional increment.  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/CSINC - the syntax takes the predicate as a final operand.  And there's a separate CSEL (like x86 cmov) / CSNEG / CSINV.

Comment: @MartinRosenau:  (In traditional ARM 32-bit, it would have been a good idea to separate the predicate from the mnemonic for the benefit of humans, but unfortunately that wasn't done.  In fact some 32-bit syntax flavours require horrible infix predicate syntax like `ldrgtb` for a byte load, and while some require `ldrbgt`.  Probably also with the S suffix for ALU instructions to set flags.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commenters have mentioned, you have the wrong guide. You need the 64-bit guide if you're looking at 64-bit code.

In A64, the instruction is formally called [`b.cond`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/B-cond), where `cond` can be any condition code.
The dot has no special meaning, just like in `ret`, the `e` has no special meaning. It's just a sequence of characters defined by ARM.

Also note that this "Reference Guide" on their website is quite malicious - for example, clicking the "Condition Codes" link on the `b.cond` page will take you out of the A64 guide and into the A32/T32 guide. I therefore recommend you [download the PDF instead](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest) and stick with it.